# Extract multiple white spaces from string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get white spaces which are greater than 1 space long.

The following gets me the null chars between each letter, and also the white spaces. However I only want to extract the two white spaces string between `c` and `d`, and the 3 white spaces string between `f` and `g`.

```
string b = "ab c  def   gh";
List<string> c = Regex.Split(b, @"[^\s]").ToList();
```

UPDATE:
The following works, but I'm looking for a more elegant way of achieving this:

```
c.RemoveAll(x => x == "" || x == " ");
```

The desired result would be a `List<string>` containing `"  "` and `"   "`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want `List<String>` as a result you could execute this *Linq* query

```
string b = "ab c  def   gh";

List<String> c = Regex
  .Matches(b, @"\s{2,}")
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

This should give you your desired List.

```
string b = "ab c  def   gh";
var regex = new Regex(@"\s\s+");
var result = new List<string>();
foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(b))
    result.Add(m.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than splitting using a Regex, try using `Regex.Matches` to get all items matching your pattern - in this case I've used a pattern to match two or more whitespace characters, which I think is what you want?

```
    var matchValues = Regex.Matches("ab c   def    gh", "\\s\\s+")
        .OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```

Annoyingly, the `MatchCollection` returned by `Regex.Matches` isn't `IEnumerable<Match>`, hence the need to use `OfType<>` in the LINQ expression.

Answer (score 2):

If all you are interested in are these groups of whitespaces, you could use

```
foreach(var match in Regex.Matches(b, @"\s\s+")) {
    // ... do something with match
}
```

This guarantees that you will match at least 2 whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following single line :

```
var list =Regex.Matches(value,@"[ ]{2,}").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();
```

Hope it will help you.